# Admob Interstitial show on any Button Click

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

how add Admob Interstitial show on any Button Click
Now it work automatically

**mainactiviti**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class PicSelect extends SherlockActivity {

private GridView photoGrid;
private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
private Itemadapter imageAdapter;
private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picselct);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#c5d951")));
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewad);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertesti
     al_id));
     mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


     mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
          @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onAdLoaded();
            if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitial.show();
          }
        }
    });

    mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
    mPhotoSpacing = 
    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);
    photoGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);
```

I tried a lot of solutions did not work for me.
plz help me thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove   `mInterstitial.show();` from `onAdLoaded()` and put it in inside of your button click calling method like below

```
btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                                    mInterstitial.show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Replace btnShow with your button on which you want to impldmem

Comment: I made her so
photoGrid.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener) {
But the application stops